# Instantiate a c++ class in FileDialog (QtQuick Object), report error: Cannot assign object to property

Tags: qml, qqmlcomponent, qqmlcontext, qqmlengine

Codes:

```
//main.qml
import im.sniper.DgConfigFileHandler 1.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
...
FileDialog{
    id: fileDlg
    DgConfigFileHandler {id: dgCfgFileHandler2}
}
```

I complie codes well and run, then get errors like:

> QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.(Crawl: That's a another problem, you can ignore)
>
> QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
>
> qrc:/main.qml:22 Cannot assign object to property

And another component like **Page**, **Window**, **Button**, can Instantiate the C++ class. What's wrong?

Comment: Should we guess what is `DgConfigFileHandler` is? And note that `FileDialog` has no [default property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#default-properties) so you cannot assign an object to it.

Comment: @folibis I do not want to assign an object, just for Instantiate a c++ class. If some qt.quick component do not support，which can, have some documentation.

Comment: Did you read about default properties? You are trying to instantiate the item as a child of `FileDialog` but it doesn't support that. You have to create your item outside of `FileDialog`, that's all.

Comment: @folibis Thanks, I Know. But I think you should be more patient. As the first question in your first comment is unnecessary , if you look at my title carefully.

Comment: You've asked a question without providing [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so no one will be able to run and test it. If you expect someone to want to spend their personal time, you should do it. My first comment answer the issue, don't it? What should I be more patient about, or what does that even mean?

Comment: I receive your criticism. But this is a knowledge problem, about whether you know. So codes **run and test** is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

That's because some components inherits `Item` which own containers, which can be used for storage `FileDialog`. See the official documentation for details, **Item QML Type**'s property [data](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#data-prop).And `FileDialog` can be added any **Item**-based type implicitly for [Default Properties](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#default-properties)(as @folibis referred to).